# С планшета на Android не заходит на ВК

Tags: android, роутер, wifi

У моей подруги не заходит в ВК с телефона на iOS и с планшета на Android, выскакивает такое сообщение: !

[image: Скрин с планшета]

Не входит только когда через Wi-Fi дома сидеть, если через 3G - то всё норм. И что ещё более странно, на компьютере тоже всё нормально входит, а ему по идее тоже роутер раздаёт интернет. Лазил в настройки маршрутизатора, пробовал заменить его ip адрес, советовали так, но всё равно та же фигня; в parental protocol тоже пусто. В hosts тоже всё норм. Из-за чего ещё может быть такая проблема?

Да, и антивирус у неё стоит Касперский. Маршрутизатор D-Link.

**UPD:**  Сделал команду в командной строке: **nslookup m.vk.com**  Выводит не то что должно:

[image: Изображение 2]

Получается, что NS сервера вообще нету, что за фигня?

**UPD2:**   С оперы мини заходит нормально

Comment: Такая же проблема, только андроид и dir-300

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что он не по теме

Answer (score 0):

mail.ru тоже не открывается, верно?На сколько мне известно это проблема с dns сервером твоего провайдера 100%, как вариант можно прописать в настройках альтернативный dns который будет выдаваться всем устройствам подключенным к роутеру либо прописать альтернативный dns в настройках проводной или беспроводной сетевой карты.

а какой провайдер?

Comment: Я не очень разбираюсь в этих настройках маршрутизатора. Где там альтернативный DNS прописать, и какой? На маил заходит, провайдер TTk, а как от провайдера может зависеть?, на компе то входит

Comment: Т.е. там где-то можно прописать для vk.com dns-сервер именно ВК и тогда он будет слушаться?

Comment: Твой dns 172.25.1.1 и ему не известен адрес m.vk.com, но известен vk.com. Можно сказать браузеру чтобы он представлялся не как планшетник, а как обычный комп, тогда при открытии vk.com не будет открываться страница(m.vk.com) для мобильных устройств.

Comment: а как это сделать?) При nslookup vk.com тоже выдаёт что не найден, т.ч. думаю надо наверно позвонить провайдеру и сказать, чтобы внёс в список днс ВК? Или где-то в настройках роутера можно проставить это? Чёртова мистика) Почему же тогда заходит на компе

Answer (score 0):

В беспроводном подключении на телефоне и планшете пропишите DNS серверы вашего провайдера.

Comment: Нету там таких настроек(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прописать DNS 8.8.8.8 (поддерживается Google)

Comment: Та где прописать то?(

Comment: вариант 1. в настройках wifi соединения на планшетевариант 2. в настройках роутера

Comment: это тогда на настройки роутера уже заходить надо будет по  8.8.8.8?

Comment: Нет, адрес самого роутера не поменяется. Но роутер будет DNS запросы посылать на тот DNS сервер, который прописан в настройках, и это должно дать позитивный эффект.

Comment: Тогда я не знаю где это менять, подскажи пож-та где в настройках роутера хотябы примерно модно DNS поменять? МОжет вообще как-то в командной строке можно поменять?

Comment: Это делается в настройках соединения с провайдером на роутере. Либо в настройках соединения на компе.

Comment: Где именно это вписать зависит от модели роутера. В общем случае методика поиска места такая: в роутере тем или иным образом прописано внешнее соединение - как правило, называется WAN. Вот в настройках этого самого соединения где-то должны быть поля для ввода адресов DNS серверов. Например, в моем роутере это выглядит так http://twitpic.com/bsy8rg Вот туда и надо прописать.